# Instantiate an object an pass it into a multiprocessing pool in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I've an object which has a method which I want to multiprocess.

```
class Driver:
   def __init__(arg1, arg2, arg3):
      #initialize
   def do_work(self, key):
      #do some work
```

I have a collection of items, I want to instantiate a driver object and pass the `do_work` function to work on 1 item of a collection.

```
arr = [# collection of strings]

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8) as pool:
     _ = pool.map(# I want to instantiate the driver and call the do_work on a one item of an array, arr)
```

I'm new to multiprocessing.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Warning: multiprocessing does not share state between the processes. If your class relies on shared state (which I guess is likely) then it won't just work, you'll have to use a strategy to share state.

Answer (score 2):

Just instantiate the class as normal. Since this is only one job, you could use apply rather than map, and this allows you to use multiple arguments as well:

```py
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8) as pool:
     driver = Driver()
     _ = pool.apply(driver.do_work, (driver, arr[some element]))
```